# Why almost every app crashes after you set up the date far away?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am using XCode 11.4 to create a simple "Single View App" from the template that XCode has.
Then, I build the app and run it on a real device iOS 6s version 13.4.1.
First time, it runs as expected. It shows only a black screen.

If I set this on the device:

Settings > Date & Time,
Turn off Set Automatically,
Change the date to 6 Jan 2034,
Kill the "Single View App",
Start it again,

It will just blink it on the screen.

Even if I set back the time to the original one, I can only recover from this if I reinstall the app.

I can not get the stack trace because I am not able to run the app again when the date is in the future, I get this message:

> A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

And I am not able to attach the debugger when it only blinks (kills instantly) the app.

I am using a paid account for this.

Here is the date and time configuration that will cause the crash:

[image: datetimecrash]

Comment: So did you get a stack traceback you can post?

Comment: You are setting the device time beyond the expiration of the provisioning profile, so the app no longer runs.  Once a provisioning profile is marked as expired even setting the date back won't unblock it.  This is to prevent you from setting your date back and running expired apps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All provisioning profiles except those issued by Apple when they sign your app for the App Store have an expiration date.

When you set your date forward you are setting it past the expiration date of your development provisioning profile. An app without a valid provisioning profile can't be launched.

Once a provisioning profile has been flagged by iOS as expired it won't be honoured, even if the date is set back; This is to prevent people from setting their device date backwards in order to run apps with expired profiles.

Comment: This totally helped me to understand this behaviour and I could not find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This because your account is a free account, and your debug project's provisioning profile will be invalid in 7 days. You can see the expired date in Xcode - Signing & Capabilities - Provisioning Profile.

Comment: Even a paid account provisioning profile would be expired in 14 years

Comment: @Paulw11, agreed. I updated the question stating that I am using a paid account.

Comment: 14 years seems a little excessive :)